# Как написать запрос, чтобы к значению каждой ячейки прибавилось 20 дней?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в БД со столбцом `"date"`. В каждой ячейке своя дата. Как написать запрос для изменения всех ячеек в столбце, чтобы к значению каждой ячейки прибавилось 20 дней?

Например: есть 1 ячейка - 01.01.2001 и 2 ячейка - 01.02.2001, нужно чтобы стало 1 ячейка - 21.01.2001 и 2 ячейка - 21.02.2001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1 SET
[Date] = DATE_ADD([Date], INTERVAL 20 DAY)
```